writing to xlsb using python not working in pandas
I am trying to write a binary excel using python using below code.
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\abc.csv')

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Desktop\final_abc.xlsb',engine='pyxlsb') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer,index=False)

Getting error pyxlsb not found

pip install pyxlsb

I have already installed the dependency pyxlsb but while writing it throws error. I searched on google and found pyxlsb only support reading is it correct? Is there any way i can write into xlsb?
